# Launch android app

Tags: android, pdf, android-emulator

I am trying to create an Android app to open a PDF file.  The goal is to be able to email them and sign them digitally.  I'm just looking to open the file by pressing a button.

The application starts but I get the following error:

```
The application "PdfSigner" has stopped unexpectedly. please try again
```

activitymain.xml :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PdfActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:text="@string/Ouvrir" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity.java :

```
    package com.example.pdfsigner;


import ltm.test.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PdfActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        //
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );
        b1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  String surl = "/ENGLISH.pdf";
  String apptype = "application/pdf";
  if( openURLWithType( surl, apptype ) == false)
          Toast.makeText( PdfActivity.this, 
       "Echec de Open URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
  }});
    }

    public boolean openURLWithType( String url, String type ) { 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.raw.ENGLISH");

        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
        intent.setDataAndType( uri, type );
        intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        try {
                PdfActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e( "LTM" ,"Activity not found: " + url, e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ltm.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PdfActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**any help or criticism will be welcome**

Comment: Please edit your answer and add stacktrace from Logcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your forgot to modify your manifest. Your `PdfActivity` is in the package `com.example.pdfsigner`.

In your manifest tag, `package="ltm.test"` should be `package="com.example.pdfsigner"`

And provide the stacktrace, you may have other errors when you launch the app.

Comment: Thank you ZouZou!

You have Given me hope, at least now my Application is Launched! I see my pretty 'Open' button, I click it and I get

Can not open URL

Well... I'll dig this problem, but if you have any ideas...

Thank you again!

Comment: @Marian Ask another question because it will be in front of the newest questions and more people will be able to help you with the problem you're facing. Add the logcat to your question =)

Comment: ok! Sorry I try to learn Android on one side and English on the other... Not easy !